Analytical solution for minimizing a functional involving a double integral
The core of diffusion models in machine learning is to find a denoiser function to approximate the diffusion noise. However, under simple settings, I would like to know if the optimal "denoiser" $f$ is able to be analytically obtained.
The generic formulation:
$$
\operatorname*{minimize}_f \mathbb{E}_{x_0,z} \lVert f(\sqrt{\alpha} x_0+\sqrt{1-\alpha} z) - z \rVert^2
$$
where $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ is a given constant, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \sim p_\text{data}$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ and $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ (a vector field).
For generic or high dimensional $p_\text{data}$, I certainly do not expect an analytical solution. But I would like to know if an analytical solution is possible with the following simplifications:

Two dimensional vector $n = 2$, and $p_\text{data}$ is chosen to be the bivariate normal distribution with non-zero covariance;
If still intractable, consider scalar case $n=1$, and and $p_\text{data}$ is chosen to be a normal distribution with non-zero mean, or one step further, unit gaussian;
Otherwise, please suggest any analytical combination of $p_\text{data}$ and $f$ to make the problem tractable.


The main difficulty is that, it seems to relate to calculus of variation, but I do not know how to handle the double integral after expanding the expectation:
$$
\operatorname*{minimize}_f \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_X(x_0) p_Z(z) \lVert f(\sqrt{\alpha} x_0+\sqrt{1-\alpha} z) - z \rVert^2 \mathop{} \mathrm{d}x_0 \mathop{} \mathrm{d}z
$$

Trivially the minimum is attained for $f(z,x_0) = \frac{z-\sqrt{\alpha}x_0}{\sqrt{1-\alpha}}$.

@Cesareo Thanks for your comment. But note that $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ takes only one vector $\sqrt{\alpha} x_0+\sqrt{1-\alpha} z$ as input. Intuitively, the denoiser $f$ takes noised input $\sqrt{\alpha} x_0+\sqrt{1-\alpha} z$ to predict noise $z$, and outer sampling loop iteratively removes the noise.

Cesareo $f$ is a function of $y=z+(\sqrt{\alpha}x_0/\sqrt{1-\alpha})$ a criteria not fulfilled  by your example.

My suggestion is to work first in one dimension and to write $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n He_n(x)$ where $He_n$ is the probabilist Hermite polynomial of degree $n.$ Since $$He_n(x+z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}He_n(z)$$ calculations $\int_{R^2}|f(\sqrt{\alpha}x+\sqrt{1-\alpha}z)|^2e^{-(x^2+z^2)/2}dxdz$ become possible and leading to the best sequence $a_n$ (the guess is that the best $f$ is linear). Too much work for me today...

Thanks for your suggestion! For the simplest case of $x_0$ subjects to one dimensional unit gaussian, using the probabilist Hermite polynomial, it turns out that $a_1 = \sqrt{1-\alpha}$ and other $a_n$ are all zero. So $f(x) = \sqrt{1-\alpha}x$ and the integral is exactly $\alpha$, which is quite reasonable and aligns with experiment results.

Before I have more time to extend the result to gaussian with non-zero mean and multivariate case, I have one more question: Is there any way to prove that the choice $f$ is indeed the optimal in all $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ mappings? Or is it possible to prove that the optimal $f$ must have the form of Hermite series?

So you did the calculation? Congratulations. The representation of a function by a sum of Hermite series is good for all functions you are interested in, namely with the suitable integrability properties.
